# assembly-maven-plug not generate jar-with-dependecies ad no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

Hi when i run mvn package the assembly plugin generate the jar name  `AnonymousChat-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` then i thought this shuld be good then i try to run this jar but i had the error "no main manifest attribute" this is the snippet of maven plugin:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>single</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                         <archive>
                           <manifest>
                             <mainClass>com.shell.Terminal</mainClass>
                           </manifest>
                          </archive>
                             <descriptorRefs>
                               <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                </descriptorRefs>
                       </configuration>
            </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Config looks okay to me. First thing I would do is to unzip the jar (7zip will do it) and check whether the manifest is actually there. Then you can see whether its a build issue or a runtime one.

Comment: I think this is the wrong jar file. Is there a file called `AnonymousChat-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` inside your target directory?

Comment: @dan1st ```AnonymousChat-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar``` this file is not present in the target directory

Comment: Any other jar files?

Comment: Only this ```AnonymousChat-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar```

Answer (score 0):

I find this code that will solve the problem, if for someone can be useful I write i here.

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.shell.Terminal</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```